# Store .fmt file in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

Is it possible to store .fmt file right in database like stored procedure, not in separate file?
Imported files varies, format file is constant for the procedure. No BLOBs, no FILESTREAM used.

```
...    
FROM OPENROWSET (
            BULK 'd:\path\some_variable_file.txt',
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FORMATFILE = 'd:\path\importformat.fmt'
        ) AS import
```

Comment: The short answer is no, but if you can explain why you want to do this then someone may have an idea. It's quite usual to have a 'library' of format files for different purposes, and since they're files they can be checked into source control too, which is very useful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPENROWSET does not support any source besides the file system for FORMATFILEs.  One option you could do is store the format file data (in either the non-xml or xml format) in a database and extract it with a powershell script